# Decoding structure use by SwiftyJson and Alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, api, alamofire, decodable

How can I decode data to a structure using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON? My attempts  give me errors like that

> "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"user\",
>   intValue: nil)

Here is my code, my try doesn't give me the result when I use non-optional values, they respond to me with NIL values

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.data != nil {
                switch response.result {
                case.failure( let error):
                    print(error)
                case.success(let val):
                    var json = JSON(val)
                    print(json)
                    guard let data = response.data else {return}
                    do {
                        let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(MainInfo.self, from: data)
                        print(root.submodel)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Bigerror")
                        print(error)
                    }
```

This is my structure

```
struct user: Codable {
    var push_id:String?
    var name:String?
    var id:String?
    var role_id:String?
    var taxi_park_id:Int?
    var car_number:String?

    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case push_id = "push_id"
        case name = "name"
        case id = "id"
        case role_id = "role_id"
        case taxi_park_id = "taxi_park_id"
        case car_number = "car_number"     
    }
}

struct MainInfo : Decodable {
    let model: String?
    let submodel: String?
    let user:user
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case model = "model"
        case submodel = "submodel"
        case user = "user"

    }
}
```

This is my pretty printed json

```
{
  "facilities" : [

  ],
  "model" : "AMC",
  "taxi_park" : "Taxi +",
  "submodel" : "Gremlin",
  "user" : {
    "role_id" : 2,
    "push_id" : "dW7Cy-ItcDo:APA91bH62zJJKKz0t9VxP29H0iE2xhnQH0hDvKpGaHc5pknuTuZq2lMaj-EapQlN3O4dJF0ysSuCNOeb-2SdJaJaLIZcwHD3CCpeNpz6UVeGktoCm2ykL2rNXF5-ofQckvz1xTvVO0V6",
    "taxi_park_id" : 0,
    "id" : 3,
    "name" : "China",
    "car_number" : "X123OOO"
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `var id:String?` to `var id: Int`. `"id" : 3` in your JSON, the value for `"id"` is a number, not a string. By the way, when you use `Codable`, you have no need to use SwiftyJSON.

Comment: "facilities" what are the possible values for it

Comment: i change it , but i'm get "keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "user", intValue: nil)"

Comment: i should Codable all variables of json ?

Comment: @ЧингизКуандык, sorry I missed `"role_id" : 2`, it's also a number. You need `var role_id: Int?`.

Comment: @ЧингизКуандык, **Codable all variables of json ?**. YES. With just a glance to your JSON example, your JSON is well structured to work with `Codable`. Dispose SwiftyJSON and go along with `Codable`.

Comment: i add all values to structure bui i get this shit keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "user", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"user\", intValue: nil) (\"user\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @ЧингизКуандык, please show your latest code. You may be missing something or you are testing with another data than you have shown. I have confirmed that with 2 fixes I mentioned above, the data you have shown successfully decoded to `MainInfo`.

Comment: @ЧингизКуандык, seems like a problem is in your data. Can you print `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, also  a simple tip, we use coding keys in swift because sometimes we have to receive an inconvenient parameter keys but we also want to use it simple and clearly in the `struct`   therefore `CodingKeys` are helpful in your case you using CodingKeys to decode the same parameter name i added the following `taxiPark`  propriety to give you a hint on why they are useful,  for example: i want to parse a `JSON` that have a key called

```
Person_ID_From_School
```

with coding keys i can do that with a better naming simple as `personId` and so on

```
 struct MainInfo : Decodable {
        let model: String?
        let submodel: String?
        let user:user
        let taxiPark: String? 
        let facilities: [String?]?
        enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
            case model = "model"
            case submodel = "submodel"
            case user = "user"
            case taxiPark = "taxi_park"
            case facilities = "facilities"

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question has nothing to do with SwiftyJSON as you are using `Codable`.

Second of all name the structs with starting capital letter (`User`), that avoids confusion like `let user : user`

The error is misleading. All `.._id` values except `push_id` are `Int` rather than `String`. It's very easy to distinguish strings from all other types: **Strings are always wrapped in double quotes**.

And if you pass the `convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy you don't need CodingKeys at all

```
struct MainInfo : Decodable {
    let model : String
    let submodel : String
    let user : User
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let pushId : String
    let name : String
    let id : Int
    let roleId : Int
    let taxiParkId : Int
    let carNumber : String
}

...

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let root = try decoder.decode(MainInfo.self, from: data)
    print(root.submodel)
} catch { print(error) }
```